My headphone mode won't turn off
I've tried everything that could make me lose this headphones mode thingy,it won't work....at all!
I've tried YouTube and google to helped me but it is useless!
I even tried using other apps to turn it off but it won't budge no matter what I do,i even clean my earphone socket 20 times!
How!?,how do I turn it off?

If I understand you correctly you have wired headphones that are connected to the headphone jack of your phone and now you want to disable the headphones to hear the sound from your hon's speaker without removing the headphone plug from your phone?
